# Why isn't jQuery Number Counter updating on html attribute change?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the [jQuery Number Counter](https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/e98c9afb475ddad0816dc7d327bdcc0b) to animate some numbers on my website. When the page is loaded the jQuery Number Counter is running fine. I am getting the numbers using an Ajax call towards my database. I am setting the data attribute 'data-to' dynamically based on the returned value from the Ajax call. However, if I initiate the Ajax call a second time with a changed data attribute value, the Number Counter runs with the initial 'data-to' value instead of the new updated value. I am not able to see why the Number Counter isn't using the new value returened by the Ajax call. Here is my code for the Number Counter initiation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getSearchCount();

    $('#tags').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
        getSearchCount();
    });

    $('#tags').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
        getSearchCount();
    });
});
```

I have verified through the console log that the value of the variable 'projectCounter' in the code below is actually changing for each Ajax call. The variable is used to set the value of the data attribute 'data-to'.

Here is the code for the Ajax call:

```
function getSearchCount()
{ 
    var sok = document.querySelector('[name="searchstring"]').value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '../../core/search/get_general_count.php', 
        data:{sok:sok}, 
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            var searchCount = response;

            for (var i in searchCount)
            {
                var countrow = searchCount[i];
                projectCount = countrow[0];
                //var profileid = profilerow[0];
                //var profiletype = profilerow[2];
            }

            $('#count-projects').attr('data-to',projectCount);
            console.log(projectCount);

            (function ($) {
                $.fn.countTo = function (options) {
                    options = options || {};

                    return $(this).each(function () {
                        // set options for current element
                        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
                            from: $(this).data('from'),
                            to: $(this).data('to'),
                            speed: $(this).data('speed'),
                            refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
                            decimals: $(this).data('decimals')
                        }, options);

                        // how many times to update the value, 
                        // and how much to increment the value on each update
                        var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
                        increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

                        // references & variables that will change with each update
                        var self = this,
                        $self = $(this),
                        loopCount = 0,
                        value = settings.from,
                        data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

                        $self.data('countTo', data);

                        // if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
                        if (data.interval) {
                            clearInterval(data.interval);
                        }
                        data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

                        // initialize the element with the starting value
                        render(value);

                        function updateTimer() {
                            value += increment;
                            loopCount++;

                            render(value);

                            if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                                settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
                            }

                            if (loopCount >= loops) {
                                // remove the interval
                                $self.removeData('countTo');
                                clearInterval(data.interval);
                                value = settings.to;

                                if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
                                    settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                function render(value) {
                    var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
                    $self.html(formattedValue);
                }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,               // the number the element should start at
        to: 0,                 // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,           // how long it should take to count between the 
        target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,           // the number of decimal places to show
        formatter: formatter,  // handler for formatting the value before 
        rendering
        onUpdate: null,        // callback method for every time the element is updated
        onComplete: null       // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };

    function formatter(value, settings) {
        return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
    }
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
// custom formatting example
$('.count-number').data('countToOptions', {
    formatter: function (value, options) {
        return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+ 
 (?!\d))/g, ' ');
    }
});

// start all the timers
$('.timer').each(count);  

function count(options) {
    var $this = $(this);
    options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') || 
{});
    $this.countTo(options);
}
});

    //alert(detrow.toString());     
  }, // end response success
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        //msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
        alert(msg);
    }
    }); //end ajax
  }; // end function
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.
I moved the jQuery Number Counter out of my Ajax function and called the jQuery Number Counter like this from my Ajax function instead.
HTML:

```
<h5 id="count-projects" class="description-header timer count-title count-number" 
 style="font-size: 40px;color: #808080;" data-to="" data-speed="500"></h5>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.timer').countTo({from: 0, to: projectCount});
```